# R - Machine Learning: Subset selection packages and approaches for a categorical response variable

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, feature-selection

I have a clinical data set with around 26 variables (mix of numerical and categorical) including response variable.

**Categorical response variable 'RETINOPATHY' has 2 factor levels: "Yes" and "No".**

Now, **the task is to find a best feature variables out of 26 total to predict the categorical response variable.** Verify the **AIC**(Akaike) etc value for different subset.

I found the library called 'leaps' is pretty handy for this task,but it works only when response variable is **Numerical**. "regsubsets" won't work for categorical variables as it's based on linear regression. see below:

```
regsubsets(finalDataDF$RETINOPATHY~., data = finalDataDF, nbest = 5, method="exhaustive")
```

In above sample, RETINOPATHY is a categorical response variable, which is a function of remaining variables.

I searched a lot but couldn't get the proper explanation like which R package is available to get the feature subsets for the prediction of RETINOPATHY.

Please guide me further. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your response is binary, why not logistic regression? It is implemented in base R function `glm`. Anyway, this is not a question for SO, since it is not about code. Maybe you could try [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I second logistic regression!

Comment: Sure, I found glm and bestglm in R. Let me try out that.